# Extracting msbuild commands from visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

Is there any way I can extract msbuild commands from visual studio 2012/2015. I am creating a command line tool where I have to write msbuild commands "manually" for the various C# projects. I wonder if it's possible to extract these commands directly from visual studio, so I will just copy & paste those commands in my tool.

Answer (score 0):

ProcMon from [SysInternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) allows you to intercept "ProcessCreate" events.

Try running it during the build of your solution and setting a filter to Process Name = "MSBuild"

This will intercept all windows events for MSBuild including process creation. If you display the event properties you can see the command line that created its process.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Moataz. The tool you mentioned was helpful in tracing MSBuild.exe process. However, I still couldn't get the exact command line for build process. I continue seeing the same command line you highlighted above.

Comment: Maybe VS launches a bunch of msbuild instances then communicates with it in another way? In any case, building in VS will also pass properties like BuildingInVisualStudio=true to the build, so you can't copy-paste msbuild commands as-is anyway since that flag should probably be fals when on the commandline

Comment: It seems devenv.exe communicates with MSBuild.exe over a an IPC pipe to do the build. Using pipelist from Sysinternals, shows a pipe to msbuild during the build process. I would go a step back and ask why do you really need to intercept the commands? Why not just use msbuild directly?

Comment: The only reason I needed msbuild commands from visual studio was to make my command line script creation faster. I have many project files and writing msbuild for each of them takes time. If I would have had msbuild commands directly from visual studio, I could simply copy and paste them here without worrying about their correctness.